# HealthCare Finder API Links Broken?

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

It seems that the HealthCare Finder API schema links are no longer working.  If you go to https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services and select any of the versions (or FAQ link) on the left-hand side, the URL updates, but only the API Overview page shows.  I have been to this site many times and have been able to access the schemas in the past, but over the last couple of weeks, nothing on the page updates.  If I go to the link directly (e.g. https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services/version_3_0) it only shows the Overview page.  Is the HealthCare Finder API broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this looks like a bug on the site. The APIs themselves seem to be working fine, but the links to the documentation are broken. If you are simply interested in the XSD then you should be able to download it from https://finder.healthcare.gov/api/finder_api_v3.0.xsd

If you are looking for a working example, try the following curl request:

```
curl 'https://api.finder.healthcare.gov/v3.0/getIFPPlanBenefits' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' --data-binary $'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> \n<p:PlanBenefitRequest xmlns:p="http://hios.cms.org/api" xmlns:p1="http://hios.cms.org/api-types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://hios.cms.org/api hios-api-11.0.xsd "> \n  <p:Enrollees>\n    <p1:DateOfBirth>1990-01-01</p1:DateOfBirth>\n    <p1:Gender>Male</p1:Gender>\n    \n    <p1:Relation>SELF</p1:Relation>\n    <p1:InHouseholdIndicator>true</p1:InHouseholdIndicator>\n  </p:Enrollees>\n  <p:Location>\n    <p1:ZipCode>48001</p1:ZipCode>\n     <p1:County>\n         <p1:FipsCode>26147</p1:FipsCode>\n         <p1:CountyName>SAINT CLAIR</p1:CountyName>\n         <p1:StateCode>MI</p1:StateCode>\n      </p1:County>\n  </p:Location>\n  <p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>2015-01-01</p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>\n  <p:Market>Individual</p:Market>\n  <p:PlanIds>\n      <p:PlanId>59830MI0010009</p:PlanId>\n</p:PlanIds>\n   </p:PlanBenefitRequest>' --compressed
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation links have been fixed. Thanks for flagging this.